# How can I compare the current time (i.e. now) to the time a certain block was mined

Tags: solidity, remix

I want to compare the time that is currently is (using block.timestamp) to a timestamp of a previous block during which the user received a token. That is I want to compare the time a user would transfer the token to the time that they had previously received the token.

Answer (score 0):

On-chain you only have access to the timestamp of the actual block. See available properries from solidity here: https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.4/units-and-global-variables.html#block-and-transaction-properties.

You can use an oracle that will answer the timestamps from previous blocks or if you can modify the token store per user the last timestamp from a transfer.